# html5 Problems with Input Field population

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i need to populate an input field based on clicking a button e.g.:

```
<input type='text' name='ta' id='ta' value='before'>

<button type="button" id="ta" onclick="myFunction()" >C</button> </td>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML = "after";
}
</script>
```

I can't get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: replace from`.innerHTML=` to `.value`

Comment: You have 'ta' id twice - that's not correct HTML... ID MUST BE UNIQUE. :)

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("ta").value = "after";
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='ta' id='ta' value='before'>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" >C</button>
```

B.T.W most browsers support now using [Named access on the Window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object), so you could significantly shorten your code this way:

```html
<input type='text' name='ta' id='ta' value='before'>
<button type="button" onclick="ta.value = 'after'" >C</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have two elements with the ID `ta`. IDs must be unique. 
So, I'd advise you change the ID of your `<input>`:

```
<input type='text' name='ta' id='exampleInput' value='before'>
```

Then, instead of change the `innerHTML` of the `<input>`, you need to change it's `value`:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("exampleInput").value = "after";
}
```